# Cut a polygon based on lines from another layer in GeoPandas

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, line, geopandas

I am trying to split a polygon based on the overlaying lines from another layer:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
import geopandas as gpd

polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
line1 = LineString([(1, 0.2), (0, 1)])
line2 = LineString([(0.6, 0), (0, 0.8)])


poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon])
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
poly_gdf.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
line_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='green')
```

[image: a polygon with two lines]

The result should be three slices of the polygon. This can be done in QGIS using the 'split with lines' processing tool, however, I am working with a larger data and I need to apply this on a scaled version of the data. How can I achieve the same result using GeoPandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - this problem is slightly trickier than it first seems because you are cutting polygons with multiple lines, and so need to do so recursively to make sure that you make all of the necessary cuts.

Here is an approach that does this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, MultiPolygon

polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
line1 = LineString([(1, 0.2), (0, 1)])
line2 = LineString([(0.6, 0), (0, 0.8)])

poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon])
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2])

# for each row in the dataset
for p_id, p_row in poly_gdf.iterrows():

    # prepare lists to control the splitting
    to_split = [p_row.geometry] # polygons that might be further split
    output = []                 # polygons that are fully split and ready to output
        
    # split the polygon and overwrite the geometry with the result
    while len (to_split) > 0:
        
        # get the next poly
        poly = to_split.pop()

        # get the lines that could split the current polygon
        lines = line_gdf.loc[(line_gdf.geometry.intersects(poly)) & (~line_gdf.geometry.touches(poly))]

        # if there is splitting to do
        if len(lines.index) > 0:

            # split using the first available line
            split_polys = split(poly, lines.geometry.iloc[0])
            
            # add the resiulting polys to the list for further splitting if required
            to_split += [p for p in split_polys.geoms]
        
        # if there is no more splitting to do with this polygon
        else:

            # add it to the output
            output.append(poly)
        

    # overwrite the geometry with the resulting multipolygon
    poly_gdf.iloc[p_id].geometry = MultiPolygon(output)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
poly_gdf.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='blue')
line_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.3, lw=5)
plt.show()
```

And here is the result:

[image]

This approach hinges on the *'intersects but does not touch'* query `line_gdf.loc[(line_gdf.geometry.intersects(poly)) & (~line_gdf.geometry.touches(poly))]`, which identifies how many lines are left that can cut the current polygon (i.e., those that intersect the polygon but not only its edge, which would indicate that it has already been used).

Using this query, we can go through each polygon and see if there is a cut to make. If so, we make one and add the results back to the list of polygons for the next iteration. If not, this means that it is fully divided and so we can add it to the output list. Once all of the polygons are in the output list, we re-assemble into a `MultiPolygon` and overwrite the old geometry in the GeoDataFrame.

---

**EDIT 1**

If you wanted the results as separate rows in the GeoDataFrame instead of a `MultiPolygon` then you can use this version instead (just one row different):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, MultiPolygon

polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
line1 = LineString([(1, 0.2), (0, 1)])
line2 = LineString([(0.6, 0), (0, 0.8)])

poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon])
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2])

# for each row in the dataset
for p_id, p_row in poly_gdf.iterrows():

    # prepare lists to control the splitting
    to_split = [p_row.geometry] # polygons that might be further split
    output = []                 # polygons that are fully split and ready to output
        
    # split the polygon and overwrite the geometry with the result
    while len (to_split) > 0:
        
        # get the next poly
        poly = to_split.pop()

        # get the lines that could split the current polygon
        lines = line_gdf.loc[(line_gdf.geometry.intersects(poly)) & (~line_gdf.geometry.touches(poly))]

        # if there is splitting to do
        if len(lines.index) > 0:

            # split using the first available line
            split_polys = split(poly, lines.geometry.iloc[0])
            
            # add the resiulting polys to the list for further splitting if required
            to_split += [p for p in split_polys.geoms]
        
        # if there is no more splitting to do with this polygon, add it to the output
        else:
            output.append(poly)
        

    # overwrite the gdf with the new polygons
    poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=output)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
poly_gdf.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='blue')
line_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.3, lw=5)
plt.show()
```

This version gives three separate polygons as three different rows in the geodataframe:

```
                                            geometry
0  POLYGON ((0.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 1.00000, 1....
1  POLYGON ((0.60000 0.00000, 0.00000 0.00000, 0....
2  POLYGON ((1.00000 0.20000, 1.00000 0.00000, 0....
```

Is that what you were after?

---

**EDIT 2**

Where the dataset of lines includes MultiLineStrings - you will need to separate the out as well - the simplest approach is just to do this prior to running the split loop. Below is an example of how this can be done:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, MultiPolygon, MultiLineString

polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
line1 = LineString([(1, 0.2), (0, 1)])
line2 = LineString([(0.6, 0), (0, 0.8)])
line3 = MultiLineString([LineString([(0.2, 0), (0, 0.4)]), LineString([(0.2, 0), (0, 0.2)])])

poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon])
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1, line2, line3])

# loop through all of your lines
line_list = []
for _, l in line_gdf.geometry.iteritems():

    # if it is a MultiLineString, separate into individuals
    if l.geom_type == 'MultiLineString':
        for l2 in l.geoms:
            line_list.append(l2)
    
    # otherwise just append
    else:
        line_list.append(l)

# then rebuild gdf with individual lines
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=line_list)

# for each row in the dataset
for p_id, p_row in poly_gdf.iterrows():

    # prepare lists to control the splitting
    to_split = [p_row.geometry] # polygons that might be further split
    output = []                 # polygons that are fully split and ready to output
        
    # split the polygon and overwrite the geometry with the result
    while len (to_split) > 0:
        
        # get the next poly
        poly = to_split.pop()

        # get the lines that could split the current polygon
        lines = line_gdf.loc[(line_gdf.geometry.intersects(poly)) & (~line_gdf.geometry.touches(poly))]

        # if there is splitting to do
        if len(lines.index) > 0:

            # split using the first available line
            split_polys = split(poly, lines.geometry.iloc[0])
            
            # add the resiulting polys to the list for further splitting if required
            to_split += [p for p in split_polys.geoms]
        
        # if there is no more splitting to do with this polygon, add it to the output
        else:
            output.append(poly)
        

    # overwrite the gdf with the new polygons
    poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=output)
    print(poly_gdf)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
poly_gdf.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='blue')
line_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.3, lw=5)
plt.show()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi jonnyhuck, thank you for your response. So I have two GPKG files, one has the polygons containing a bunch of information and the other has lines (again with a bunch of variables). I am trying to slice all the polygons into separate areas. The solution that you have provided does not seem to give me three separate polygons. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Salahuddin, it does, but has them wrapped in a multi polygon,   Right at the end of my post it suggests one line that you can change if you want them on separate rows or the GeoDataframe (I wasn’t sure which way around you wanted it) if you swap that line it should give you what you are after. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think it makes sense. I tried your code but I am getting the following error:
'Sequences of multi-polygons are not valid arguments'

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer so that it has a full version of the code that outputs three polygons as three separate rows in the geodataframe (the code below the image) - can you just run that and confirm that it works for you? It does for me.

Comment: Now its throwing the following error: 'Splitting a Polygon with a MultiLineString is not supported'

Comment: I think your solution works. I just can't seem to apply it on my data. I am working with two GPKG files (one has the following variables ['OBJECTID', 'DFIRM_ID', 'VERSION_ID', 'FLD_AR_ID', 'STUDY_TYP',
       'FLD_ZONE', 'ZONE_SUBTY', 'SFHA_TF', 'STATIC_BFE', 'V_DATUM', 'DEPTH',
       'LEN_UNIT', 'VELOCITY', 'VEL_UNIT', 'AR_REVERT', 'AR_SUBTRV',
       'BFE_REVERT', 'DEP_REVERT', 'DUAL_ZONE', 'SOURCE_CIT', 'GFID',
       'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area', 'geometry']

Comment: The second GPKG file has lines and has the following attributes: ['OBJECTID', 'DFIRM_ID', 'VERSION_ID', 'BFE_LN_ID', 'ELEV', 'LEN_UNIT', 'V_DATUM', 'SOURCE_CIT', 'GFID', 'Shape_Length', 'geometry']

Comment: OK - I think that the problem here is that the solution solves your question - but the question does not fully reflect the problem that you are having (if you are happy to mark it as the answer on this basis, please do so) - this is why it works on your samle code but not your real data. The difference is that your dataset has `MultiLineStrings` in it, whereas your question only had `LineStrings` - this is the cause of the error that you are getting. I have added another answer that solves this problem as well (at the bottom of my post). How is that?

Comment: for _, l in line_gdf.geometry.iteritems(): - iteritems() had been deprecated and removed in Pandas 2.0. Now uses items() instead. https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference/issues/1640